# Bootstrap 4 Spacing utilities only for specific breakpoint not for all the breakpoint greater than the mentioned breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to apply padding for an HTML element only for small devices i.e)  pl-4. But in bootstrap 4 that same padding applies for mentioned breakpoint along with all the greater breakpoint. Like specifically hiding elements for a specific media query. I want to apply padding only for small devices. Is it possible in bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Spacing utilities that apply to all breakpoints, from xs to xl, have no breakpoint abbreviation in them. This is because those classes are **applied from min-width: 0 and up**, and thus are not bound by a media query. The remaining breakpoints, however, do include a breakpoint abbreviation.

The above statement is from Bootstrap 4 documentation it clearly explains what I need. But my request to Bootstrap developers to make/set a bounding media query for spacing utilities also.